# What word am I after the clues?

Tags: riddle, word

1. My prefix is a basic food in a western romance language
2. My infix is an ancient God, and if you write it 10 times with no spaces in Google you can find some videos in youtube with exact name
3. My suffix is an anagram of a music chord acronym (by this I mean the full chord as written in a tab, not the alteration alone)
4. Change one phoneme in me and I become the anagram of a muscle
5. Remove one letter from me and I become the anagram of some kind of visual representation

Comment: I know the infix, and I'm fairly sure I know the muscle, and maybe the visual representation, but that's still not enough to figure out the word ...

Comment: If you knew the muscle and the infix I think you'd already knew the answer.  Indeed, I think knowing for sure 1/2 out of the 5 clues, unveils automatically the rest. The most difficult is 1, but at the same time is the easiest since you can get by heuristic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am quite certain you are a

> **paradigm**

1. My prefix is a basic food in a western romance language

> [**Para**](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&sxsrf=ALeKk02W-wD1v-eDx7ako6FFjZJKoeaXtQ%3A1583130664263&ei=KKhcXtzKD-Tdz7sPp4q3yAQ&q=para+in+romanian&oq=para+in+romanian&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30.9066.16158..16481...1.2..1.319.3534.8j12j3j2......0....1..gws-wiz.....10..0i71j0i20i263j0j0i131j0i10j35i362i39j35i39j0i67j0i70i255j0i10i70i255j33i22i29i30j0i22i10i30.zLhr4MenaQY&ved=0ahUKEwjc_oCnlfvnAhXk7nMBHSfFDUkQ4dUDCAs&uact=5) stands for pear in Romanian.

2. My infix is an ancient God, and if you write it 10 times with no spaces in Google you can find some videos in youtube with exact name

> [**Ra**](https://www.google.com/search?q=rararararararararara&oq=rararararararararara&aqs=chrome..69i57.5465j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), an ancient Egyptian God.

3. My suffix is an anagram of a music chord acronym

> [**Gdim**](https://www.pianochord.org/g-dim.html) is a music chord.

4. Change one phoneme in me and I become the anagram of a muscle

> *paradigm* $\to$ *diapragm* $\to$ [***diaphragm***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thoracic_diaphragm) if phoneme **/p/** is replaced with **/f/**

5. Remove one letter from me and I become the anagram of some kind of visual representation

> The word *paradigm* becomes **diagram** by removing the letter **p**

Comment: Amazing! The prefix is "pa" which stands for bread in catalan language

Answer (score 0):

You are

> Pyramid.

My prefix is a basic food in a western romance language

> Pie. There are few things as American as apple pie. Sounds like **Py**.

My infix is an ancient God, and if you write it 10 times with no spaces in Google you can find some videos in youtube with exact name

> **Ra** was the ancient Egyptian deity of the sun, order, kings, and the sky.

My suffix is an anagram of a music chord acronym

> Dim is a symbol used for notating chords that indicates a diminished chord. Anagram of **mid**.

Change one phoneme in me and I become the anagram of a muscle

> The [pyramidalis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramidalis_muscle) muscle is a small triangular muscle contained in the rectus sheath.

Remove one letter from me and I become the anagram of some kind of visual representation

> [Myriad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myriad) is most commonly used to mean some large but unspecified number. Anagram of **yramid**.

Comment: This isn't very convincing. English isn't a Romance language; you aren't "Chang[ing] one phoneme" to get the muscle; and a large but unspecified number isn't "some kind of visual representation".

Comment: Unfortunately @Rand al'Thor is right. But your attempt is not absolutely far from the answer